# Sort Rows Alphabetically in DF

Tags: python

I have a df with a bunch of rows with names, like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | Mark | Andrew |
| Dave | Eric | Bill |

I want to sort the names in every row alphabetically from left to right, starting at col2.

Desired output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | Andrew | Mark |
| Dave | Bill | Eric |

I have tried something like this, but it is rearranging the names in the first column to different rows.

`df[['col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df[['col2', 'col3']].apply(sorted, axis=1).values)).T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets do sort using `np.sort` and assign the sorted values back to dataframe:

```
c = df.columns[1:]
df[c] = np.sort(df[c], axis=1)
```

##### Result

```
   col1    col2  col3
0  Josh  Andrew  Mark
1  Dave    Bill  Eric
```